# Inline Image is not displayed in the HTML Mail generated by google script

Tags: javascript, html, image, email

I made a simple google script to send html emails with inline images. Below is part of my code:

```js
var htmlBody =       HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('mail_template').getContent();

MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {htmlBody:htmlBody});
```

---

and in "mail_template":

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
<table style='max-width: 900px' width='100%'>
<tr>
<td>
<img src='https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-oaZl4KUUUQYTBWWF9MU2lURlU' width='100%'>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The image is broken in the mail: 
[broken image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVs9l.png)

Comment: It asks for permission when you go to that link.  You need to put the image somewhere that's accessible to the public, without any type of authentication.

Comment: You need to upload the image somewhere that isn't behind a login screen and returns a valid image - for example if you used http://i.stack.imgur.com/jVs9l.png as a temp image in your email, it would work.

Comment: Hi Archer, Thanks for your response. However, I tested it within a normal html file, it can be displayed. <img src='https://googledrive.com/host/0B-oaZl4KUUUQSENDYXhPMENMWjQ/lastdinnersmall.png' width='100%'>             The image file is uploaded in a public folder in google drive that is shared to everyone.    I also tested using the shared link of that image.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by changing the image url. In fact, for the images in Google Drive, it can be displayed in Email only if the format is like below: `drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=FILEID`.

I found [this article](http://googlesystem.blogspot.in/2013/02/permalinks-for-google-drive-images.html) which helped.